# Is there a way to replace individual array elements with one repeated element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to replace the elements of an array with 1 element repeated for each index.

E.g.
`['12','a','drink','cookie']` becomes `['0','0','0','0']`

I'm learning basic `JavaScript` and trying to figure out how to do this. I've tried `forEach()` and `splice()` but I keep ending up with just one index (e.g. `['0']`). I feel like I can solve this with a `for` loop but what to put in? The code below is my latest effort but it didn't run.

```
function replace()
{
    var Word = 'test';
    var newWordArray = Array.from(Word);

    for (var i = 0; i < newWordArray.length; i++); {
        i = '0';
    }
}
```

I expect `['0','0','0','0']` as output, but I get undefined when trying to run the function.

Comment: seems like you want [array.fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues with your code:

1. `i = '0'` isn't doing what you think it is doing. Here `i` is just a number, representing an index in your array. Changing `i` will do nothing as you're not doing anything with the value of `i` itself. Instead your need to change the element at index `i`. You can do this by doing `newWordArray[i] = 0`. This way you are saying change the element at index `i` in your array `newWordArray`.
2. You are not returning anything from your function. In order for your function to get assigned a value once called, you need to `return` said value. Thus, as you want your function call to output (return) a new array, you need to `return newWordArray` at the end of your function.
3. Although it isn't necessary, I suggest that you add a parameter to your function called `word`. This way the function can accept a string (or array) and give you the required output.

See working example below:

```js
function replace(word) { // accept a word as an input to use in your function
  var newWordArray = Array.from(word); // create an array of characters from your inputted word
  for (var i = 0; i < newWordArray.length; i++) { // remove ';' colon here
    newWordArray[i] = 0; // Set every element (by accessing it using its index 'i') to 0
  }
  return newWordArray; // output (return) the new array
}

console.log(replace("test")); // input "test" as the word variable
console.log(replace(['12','a','drink','cookie']));
```

Also note `Array.from([1, 2, 3])` will give an array in return, so `[1, 2, 3]`. Thus the above works on both strings and arrays.

Alternatively, a different approach to achieving the same thing as above would be to use [`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill). Here I have used [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const replace = ({length}) => Array(length).fill(0);
console.log(replace("testing"));
console.log(replace(['12','a','drink','cookie']));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Nick Parsons**, already explained so good how to change your code to approach your goal, however, and since you are already using [Array::from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Syntax), you can use the `mapFn` argument and reduce your code to be more simple, like this:

```js
const replace = (word, replaceVal) => Array.from(word, x => replaceVal);

console.log(replace("word", 0));
console.log(replace("Hello World", 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to assign it to each element in the array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < newWordArray.length; i++); {
    newWordArray[i] = '0';
}
```

You were assigning the value to the iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Here array map shortens your code

```js
var Word = 'test';
//var newWordArray = Array.from(Word);
let j=Array.from(Word).map(a=>a='0');
console.log(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer splice and forEach to achieve this

```
var contents = ['a','b','c','d'];
document.getElementById('LW').value = contents 

contents.forEach(function(element, index) {
    contents.splice(index, 1, "0");
});
```